# Book recommendation for Jewish mindfulness

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, mussar-ethics

My Yom Kippur "cheshbon hanefesh" taught me that I should train myself to be conscious of the purpose of each activity, however trivial, as I engage in it through the day.

(I think that this might be similar to what is achieved through “Mindfulness”.)

Is there a book in English or Hebrew which would help me achieve my purpose?

Comment: http://www.feldheim.com/halachos-of-brochos.html

Comment: Start with Chovot Halevavot by Rabenu Bechaye...Feldheim publishers has a great version....Trust me!

Comment: Haven't read it yet so I can't speak to the content, but [_Jewish Meditation: A Practical Guide_ by Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan](https://www.amazon.com/Jewish-Meditation-Practical-Aryeh-Kaplan/dp/0805210377) might be of use.

Comment: "I should train myself to be conscious of the purpose of each activity, however trivial, as I engage in it through the day." - This is the entire purpose of the Mussar movement.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books/about/Living_in_the_Presence.html?id=xlvADwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&gboemv=1&ovdme=1#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 3):

There are a few books out there. One of them is called [It's All The Same To Me: A Torah Guide To Inner Peace and Love of Life](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1736139002), written by Moshe Gersht. It talks about being in the present moment and stuff like that, you may enjoy it.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider the book published by Feldheim, *[Mindfulness, A Jewish Approach](https://www.feldheim.com/mindfulness)* authored by Jonathan Feiner.

The blurb reads as follows:

> *"In Mindfulness: A Jewish Approach, Dr. Jonathan Feiner does a masterful job educating our minds and hearts in the understanding and practice of Jewish mindfulness. In an age of distraction and fragmentation this book uses Jewish wisdom, coupled with secular approaches in an integrated manner that serves as a roadmap to living life with greater awareness, purpose, and ability to live more fully in the present”*
>
> -David Pelcovitz, Ph.D. Straus Chair in Psychology and Education, Azrieli Graduate School, Yeshiva University
>
> *“An incisive and impressive book …the teachings of Chazal, the insights of the Baalei Mussar, the inspiration of Chassidus, and the profundities of Kabbala are deftly joined with contemporary psychology and the mindfulness literature to create a comprehensive workable framework to achieve true inner peace and harmony.”*
>
> -Rabbi Dr. Yitzchak Breitowitz Rav, Kehillat Ohr Somayach
>
> *“Weaving together myriad outlooks and insights, illuminating vignettes, and life lessons culled from a vast array of both Jewish and secular sources, Dr. Jonathan Feiner has succeeded beautifully in presenting the reader with a rich and enlightening tapestry on the topic of mindfulness…Interesting and informative, powerful and thought-provoking, Mindfulness: A Jewish Approach challenges us to be more acutely aware and mindful of the present moment, to ponder “the real me”, and to pay far closer attention the people and events that surround us daily.”*
>
> -Rabbi Eytan Feiner Rav, Congregation Kneseth Israel